# trying to test my db using testcontainers but got a runtime error: index out of range

Tags: docker, go, testing

I'm trying to test my database using testcontainers. I've copied some code from https://gist.github.com/Eun/221e9cb9190b56578dbb752e5e2a6b2a and edited it the way I need it:

```
type TestNoteEditor struct {
    db *gorm.DB
    NoteEditor
    instance testcontainers.Container
}

type TestDatabase struct {
    instance testcontainers.Container
}

const DBSource = "postgresql://%s:%s@%s/%d?sslmode=disable"

func NewTestDatabase(t *testing.T) *TestNoteEditor {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "postgres:12",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"5432/tcp"},
        AutoRemove:   true,
        Env: map[string]string{
            "POSTGRES_USER":     "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_DB":       "postgres",
        },
        WaitingFor: wait.ForListeningPort("5432/tcp"),
    }

// the error occurs on the line below
    postgresContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("GenericContainer err = ", err)
    }

    require.NoError(t, err)

    testDb := TestDatabase{instance: postgresContainer}
    port := testDb.Port(t)
    source := fmt.Sprintf(DBSource, "postgres", "postgres", "postgres", port)

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(source), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Msg("cannot create gorm")
    }

    return &TestNoteEditor{
        db:       db,
        instance: postgresContainer,
    }
}

func (db *TestDatabase) Port(t *testing.T) int {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()
    p, err := db.instance.MappedPort(ctx, "5432")
    require.NoError(t, err)
    return p.Int()
}

func (db *TestDatabase) ConnectionString(t *testing.T) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:%d/postgres", db.Port(t))
}

func (db *TestDatabase) Close(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()
    require.NoError(t, db.instance.Terminate(ctx))
}
```

here is how I try to run this code:

```
func TestDatabase_SaveNote(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        n notes.UserNoteRequest
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        db      *TestNoteEditor
        args    args
        want    Note
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {
            name: "positive test",
            db:   &TestNoteEditor{},
            args: args{
                n: notes.UserNoteRequest{
                    User:   297850814,
                    Title:  "test #1",
                    Photos: []notes.UserPhoto{},
                },
            },
            want: Note{
                ID:       1,
                User:     1,
                Title:    "test #1",
                Created:  time.Now(),
                HasPhoto: false,
            },
            wantErr: false,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {

            tt.db = NewTestDatabase(t)
        })
    }
}
```

But when I run this code I always got an error in the NewTestDatabase function. Here is the error:

```
2023/07/07 18:00:34 Starting container id: c952804c376e image: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3
2023/07/07 18:00:34 Waiting for container id c952804c376e image: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3
--- FAIL: TestDatabase_SaveNote (0.47s)
    --- FAIL: TestDatabase_SaveNote/positive_test (0.47s)
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0 [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 23 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0xb690a0, 0xc0001120a8})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/golang/go1.20rc3/go1.20rc3/src/testing/testing.go:1526 +0x24e
testing.tRunner.func1()
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/golang/go1.20rc3/go1.20rc3/src/testing/testing.go:1529 +0x39f
panic({0xb690a0, 0xc0001120a8})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/golang/go1.20rc3/go1.20rc3/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x213
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.(*DockerContainer).MappedPort(0xcc4658?, {0xcc45e8, 0xc00017a000}, {0xbb5d29, 0x8})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/docker.go:128 +0x2e5
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/wait.(*HostPortStrategy).WaitUntilReady(0xc0000082a0, {0xcc4658?, 0xc0003ec510?}, {0xcc4850, 0xc00026a000})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/wait/host_port.go:59 +0x11a
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.(*DockerContainer).Start(0xc00026a000, {0xcc4658, 0xc0003ec510})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/docker.go:160 +0x1bc
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.(*DockerProvider).RunContainer(_, {_, _}, {{{0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}}, {0xbca790, ...}, ...})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/docker.go:642 +0x95
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.NewReaper({0xcc4658, 0xc0003ec510}, {0xc00017d920, 0x24}, {0xcbc2c0, 0xc000008258}, {0x0, 0x0})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/reaper.go:73 +0x44d
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.(*DockerProvider).CreateContainer(_, {_, _}, {{{0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}}, {0xbb82a8, ...}, ...})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/docker.go:479 +0x385
github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go.GenericContainer({_, _}, {{{{0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}}, {0xbb82a8, 0xb}, ...}, ...})
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.7.0/generic.go:43 +0x89
github.com/Pizhlo/tgbot-reminder-go/internal/db/postgresql.NewTestDatabase(0xc0002669c0)
    c:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/main_test.go:42 +0x2d1
github.com/Pizhlo/tgbot-reminder-go/internal/db/postgresql.TestDatabase_SaveNote.func1(0x0?)
    c:/Users/pizhlo21/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/notes_test.go:45 +0x25
testing.tRunner(0xc0002669c0, 0xc0001ca5e0)
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/golang/go1.20rc3/go1.20rc3/src/testing/testing.go:1576 +0x10b
created by testing.(*T).Run
    C:/Users/pizhlo21/golang/go1.20rc3/go1.20rc3/src/testing/testing.go:1629 +0x3ea
FAIL    github.com/Pizhlo/tgbot-reminder-go/internal/db/postgresql  0.890s
FAIL
```

Is there any ways to fix this? thank you in advance!

Comment: my guess would be that you're not supplying some required field in NewTestDatabase's ContainerRequest

Answer (score 0):

@pizhlo, you probably want to look at the Postgres module: https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/postgres/

The main difference is that the module comes with predefined wait strategies, which I think it's the root cause for your test to fail: you are defining a wait strategy that waits for the port to be available, but we internally check that the Postgres logs contain two times the "database system is ready to accept connections" entry.

In your code, I'd try with this wait strategy first:

```golang
wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
            WithOccurrence(2).
            WithStartupTimeout(5*time.Second))
```

Or just switch to the module, reducing your code by importing the module.

Comment: thank you! gonna try your solution later :)

Comment: Any progress with this? 